# Kotlin actor coroutine and concurrency issue

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

When looking at the example  https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/guide/example-sync-07.kt , more specifically at the following fragment

```
// This function launches a new counter actor
fun CoroutineScope.counterActor() = actor<CounterMsg> {
    var counter = 0 // actor state
    for (msg in channel) { // iterate over incoming messages
        when (msg) {
            is IncCounter -> counter++
            is GetCounter -> msg.response.complete(counter)
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot but notice that if for example 5 other coroutines send GetCounter message to the above actor,  they will be "served" sequentially one after another, i.e. no parallelism is achieved. Even although we have a CPU with 8 physical threads, each of "client" coroutines reading the counter value will be constrained by a sequential execution of the actor coroutine.

How can we avoid this sequential processing when using actor coroutine?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean this specific example, incrementing a counter is not something that parallelizes, at least not with any general approach. If you ask more generally, the actor can easily launch an expensive async computation in `Dispatchers.Default` and get it parallelized.

Comment: I was asking for a way to parallelize read access to the data owned by an actor.

Comment: Have you tried to launch sub-coroutines yet?  I think `launch` is a better fit than `async` because you push the result into the response. The launched job can do that.